# How to check if cv2.rectangle lies inside cv2.rectangle in opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have one coordinate for rectangle

```
cv2.rectangle(image, (245, 158), (721, 924), color, 2)
```

where it identifies the **person(main object)**.

I have one more coordinate for the helmet which detected inside of my first rectangle

```
cv2.rectangle(image, (415, 180), (650, 345), color, 2)
```

[image]

Now in code, I have to check the condition that how many rectangles are identified within the main rectangle **(person is my main object)**.

Can anyone please suggest me a good way. Please. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess since you have the coordinates you can just check if the ones for the helmet lie in the middle of the coordinates of the person

```
px1, py1, px2, py2 = 245, 158, 721, 924
hx1, hy1, hx2, hy2 = 415, 180, 650, 345
if hx1 >= px1 and hy1 >= py1 and hx2 <= px2 and hy2 <=py2:
    # do whatever
```

If you want to utilize `cv2` and find the area where it has gone out then you can take a blank NumPy array of zeros of the same size as your image, draw the person square in white, perform its inverse and then do an XOR operation with another array of the same size which has the helmet drawn in white. This way you will get the area outside the person.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

h, w = image[:2]
p_img = np.zeros((w, h), dtype=np.uint8)
h_img = np.zeros((w, h), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(p_img, (245, 158), (721, 924), (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv2.rectangle(h_img, (415, 180), (650, 345), (255, 255, 255), -1)
p_img = cv2.bitwise_not(p_img)
res = cv2.bitwise_xor(p_img, h_img)
```